# How to display the length of an Array in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to create a small social media app. Everything works fine so far, but when I am trying to show the length off an `Array` (which saves the friends of a `User` in the `ProfilView`), I am getting the Error `"No exact matches in call to initializer"`

```
Capsule()
    .frame(width: 110, height: 30)
    .offset(x: 40)
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
    .overlay(
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "person.3.fill")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .position(x: 120, y: 15)
            Text(appUser.friends.count)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .position(x: 35, y: 15)
                .frame(width: 70, height: 30, alignment: .trailing)
        }
    )
```

```
class User: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var username: String = ""
    @Published var name: String = ""
    var password: String = ""
    @Published var email: String = ""
    @Published var beschreibung: String = ""
    @Published var profilBild: UIImage?
    
    @Published var friends = [User]()
    
    
    init(_ username: String, _ password: String, _ email: String, _ name: String) {
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.email = email
        self.name = name
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to send an `Int` to `Text`, which expects a `String` in its initializer.

You could interpolate the variable into a `String`:

```
Text("\(appUser.friends.count)")
```

Or, you could pass the `Int` into a `String` initializer:

```
Text(String(appUser.friends.count))
```